# Which page was just shown?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In 1.4.2, I have this:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', PageShown);

function PageShown(myEvent, myUI ) {
    log(this)
    log(myEvent)
    log(myUI)
};
```

I can't determine which page was just shown.
If I add more specificity to the selector, the event doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

As of jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 you can access previous `.prevPage` and next page `.toPage`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
  var activePage   = ui.toPage,
      previousPage = ui.prevPage;
});
```

Both are jQuery objects so `$()` isn't needed.

---

To determine which page is currently active, you have two options:

1. Listen to `pagecontainerhide` and check `ui.nextPage` object emitted by that event

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function (e, ui) {
     var activePage = $(ui.nextPage);
   });
   ```
2. On `pagecontainershow`, use the below function which will return active page.

   ```
   var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
   ```

Read more about [page events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/).