# How to retrieve the page I'm using (JQuery's data-role attribute)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have:

```
<div id="page-1" data-role="page">
</div>

<div id="page-2" data-role="page">
</div>
```

in my javascript code in some function I will write:

```
 $.mobile.navigate('page-2');
```

and in another function I will want to retrieve the page that I'm current using:

(in this example page-2)

Is there a way of doing this without using a global variable? (by using some method?)

Comment: Will the page refresh with each click? Or ajax in the new content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which page was just shown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121564/which-page-was-just-shown)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking. But if you are trying to get the id of the page, you would do something like this:

```
var activepage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
if(activepage[0].id == "page-1")
{   /* do something here */ }
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage)

Comment: @Selvaraj make sure you edit code _correctly_. it's `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer`, why did you remove `.pageContainer`?

Comment: @Omar Apologies, My mistake